# linq orderby issue (sorting strings by custom rules)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

I have a linq query which is not ordered the way I would like.

The Query:

```
return (from obj in context.table_orders
    orderby obj.order_no
    select obj.order_no.ToString() + '-' + obj.order_description).ToList<string>();
```

What happens is that my records are ordered alphabeticaly, is there a Linq keyword I can use so my records are ordered correctly (so order 30 comes before order 100)?

I want the result to be a list of string since this is used to populate a ComboBox.

Also some of the 'order_no' in the DB are like '2.10' and '9.1.1'.

Comment: so `order_no` is not actually a number?

Comment: no n the database it's a varchar (ex: '10.1')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody came up with a custom orderby function translatable into SQL, I went for the IComparer function like so:

```
    public class OrderComparer<T> : IComparer<string>
    {
        #region IComparer<string> Members

        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            return GetOrderableValue(x.Split('-').First()).CompareTo(GetOrderableValue(y.Split('-').First()));
        }
        #endregion

        private int GetOrderableValue(string value)
        {
            string[] splitValue = value.Split('.');
            int orderableValue = 0;
            if (splitValue.Length.Equals(1))
                orderableValue = int.Parse(splitValue[0]) * 1000;
            else if (splitValue.Length.Equals(2))
                orderableValue = int.Parse(splitValue[0]) * 1000 + int.Parse(splitValue[1]) * 100;
            else if (splitValue.Length.Equals(3))
                orderableValue = int.Parse(splitValue[0]) * 1000 + int.Parse(splitValue[1]) * 100 + int.Parse(splitValue[2]) * 10;
            else
                orderableValue = int.Parse(splitValue[0]) * 1000 + int.Parse(splitValue[1]) * 100 + int.Parse(splitValue[2]) * 10 + int.Parse(splitValue[3]);

            return orderableValue;
        }
    }
```

The values have a maximum of 4 levels.
Anyone has a recommandation?

Comment: see my answer for proposed logic for the comparer - you wouldn't need this if/else block, but you could foreach through the seequences

Comment: maybe too old but i would suggest something like
int val = 0; value.Split('.').toList().ForEach(v =>  val += v);

Answer (score 3):

> What happens is that my records are ordered alphabeticaly, is there a Linq keyword I can use so my records are 
>   ordered correctly (so order #30 comes before order #100)?

If I would get a cente everytime someone asks this I would be rich.

Yes, there is - simple answer: ORDER A NUMBER NOT A STRING.

> so order #30 comes before order #100)

But #30 comes AFTER #100 for the simple reason that they ARE sorted alphabetically becase THEY ARE STRINGS.

Parse the string, convert the number to - well - a number, and order by it.

WHOEVER had the idea that order_no should be a string WITHOUT A FIXED LENGH (like 00030) should - well - ;) get a basic education on database modelling. I really like things like invoice numbers etc. to be strings (they are NOT numbers) but keeping them in (a) a defiable pattern and (b) checksummed (so that data entry errors are easily catched) should be basics ;)

This is the kind of issue you get with junior people defining databases and data models and not thinking about the consequences.

You are in for some pain - parse the string, order by parsing result.

Comment: actually it's not an order table and the number is acting more like a identification tag with dots instead of commas.

Answer (score 0):

If `obj.order_no` is a string, then convert it to a number for sorting

```
orderby Int32.Parse(obj.order_no)
```

or

```
orderby Decimal.Parse(obj.order_no)
```

of cause this works only if the string represents a valid number.

---

If `order_no` is not a valid number (e.g. `"17.7-8A"`) then write a function that formats it to contain right aligned numbers, like `"00017.007-0008A"` and sort using this function

```
orderby FormatOrderNo(obj.order_no)
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since you are working with EF you cannot call this function in the EF part of your query. Convert the EF-result to an `IEnumerable<T>` and perform the sorting using LINQ-To-Objects

```
return (from obj in context.table_orders select ...)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(obj => FormatOrderNo(obj.order_no))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not certain, but I don't think this would work in a linq-to-sql context

Comment: nope did not work. (Method 'System.Decimal Parse(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.) but good try: I'm looking for something like that.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of LINQ-to-objects. Sort it afterwards `return (from obj in context.table_orders select ...).AsEnumerable().OrderBy(obj => FormatOrderNo(obj.order_no)).ToList();`

Comment: The perfomrmance implication of that is HUGH. Pulls all objects into memory THEN sorts.... can make ahugh difference.

Comment: The `.ToList()` puts it to memory anyway and sorting on the client is not necessarily more slowly than sorting on the server, especially when no index can be used. Maybe it is somewhat more efficient to perform the sorting with one of the `List.Sort()` overloads instead (at least in terms of memory usage).

Comment: I can't use the .OrderBy on the obj.order_no because the query returns a simple string which has no order_no... how could I define a SQL compatible orderby functioN?

Comment: See my update. The part after `.AsEnumerable` is not performed on the database but inside your application and needs not be SQL compatible. If you format the order numbers as '0002.010.00' and '0009.001.01', why should it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said - that the numbers are not really numbers but rather custom sequence identifiers (i.e. you don't even know what level of depth you get) I would suggest implementing a custom comparer.

If you do this you can define what you exaclty want - and that is I believe something along these lines:

- split the string on `.`
- compare the sequences up to and including the array.length of the shorter sequence
- if there was a shorter sequence and by now there is a tie, pick the shorter before the longer (i.e. `2.1` before `2.1.1`)
- if both sequences had the same length, by the end of the comparison you should know which one is 'bigger'
- solved.

If you need inspiration on `IComparer` implementation an example below:
http://zootfroot.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/natural-sort-compare-with-linq-orderby.html

Answer (score 0):

I would either change the datatype if possible or add it as another firld if applicable.
If that is a no-go you can look at the solutions mentioned by others in this question but beware - The .ToList() option is nice for small tables if you are pulling everything from them but getting used to it will eventually give you a world of pain. You don't wanna get everything in the long run, either use a Where or top critera.

The other solutions are nice but to complex for my taste to accomplish the task.

You could go with shooting sql directly through LinqToSql. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399403.aspx

In the sql you are free to convert and sort however you like. Some think this is a great idea and some will tell you it it bad. You loose strong typing and gain performance. You will have to know WHY you take this kinds of decision, that is the most important thing imho.